# endScreen Play Again Button Problem How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

I made an endscreen when ever my player health  reaches -1 it loads the end screen but here is the problem   [Video](https://gyazo.com/1db8a0f5b5b7214ab7d0b72a2566ab7c) it wont restart the game and I have to hold the start game to show my main game

my end screen def ***my point is how could I make it restart my game to the start not just blit the game where I was***

```
#------------------------------------------------------


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def endScreen():
    red = (200,0,0)
    green = (0,200,0)
    bright_red = (255,0,0)
    bright_green = (0,255,0)

    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('BLOODY.ttf',81)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("You Have Died Fool", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((800/2), (800/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        button("Start Game",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)

# make the square brighter if collideded with the buttons
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if 150+120 > mouse[0] > 150 and 450+50 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, bright_green,(150,450,120,50))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, green,(150,450,120,50))
        if 550+110 > mouse[0] > 550 and 450+50 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, bright_red,(550,450,110,50))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, red,(550,450,110,50))
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Start Game", smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (150+(120/2)), (450+(50/2)) )
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)


        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Quit Game", smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (150+(910/2)), (450+(50/2)) )
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



#----------------------------------------------------------
```

here is what I did in my main loop
when my player health reaches 0 it shows the end screen

```
def game_loop():



    # coin scoring
    font = pygame.font.Font('times.ttf',29)
    score = 0
    text = font.render("Hearts  =   " + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ((80,70))
    shootsright = []
    bullets = []
    bulls = []
    bullss = []
    bullsss = []
    bullssss = []
    runninggame = True
    while runninggame:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                runninggame = False


            if playerman.health < -5:
                endScreen()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all of your game loop variables have been saved so when you restart you still have all the variables set to what they when you died.

So what you will need to do is put everything in one giant while loop. For example:

```
import ...

quit = False
while not quit:
   # all of your code goes here
```

But once you do this you must change the pygame.QUIT if statement in your game loop as follows:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
   runninggame = False
```

|

 V

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
   sys.exit()
```

and the same goes for the pygame.QUIT at the top of your endScreen function.

**Change 1:** The next thing that must be changed is exiting the game loop function. This can be done by modifying one of the button functions to return a bool stating whether or not the restart button was clicked. From there that value can be passed onto the game loop function and if the button is pressed the while loop in the function will be broken out of causing everything in the while loop to rerun.

**Explanation:** Currently, the problem is that you never exit the loop meaning when you click the retry button you just start right back from where you let off. Instead, you need to redefine all your variables which is why all the code needs to be in a while loop (you can actually leave out the functions all that needs to be in the while loop are the global variables, but it is not necessary to move the functions out).

**Change 2 (minor changes):** Sys needs to be imported at the top of the script and the pygame.quit() function at the end of the script needs to be deleted.

**Explanation:** Sys is imported so that sys.exit can be run which allows the program to be terminated once the window is closed out. The pygame.quit() is deleted because running that will uninitialized pygame and that would prevent you from using any pygame functions after you have pressed the retry button. And this code is no longer necessary since sys.exit() pretty much just takes care of all that for you.

And a minor note: enemys should actually be enemies (it would look bad if you had the word enemies spelled incorrectly in your code and you put it up on GitHub) so I recommend just doing a quick replace all.

Comment: so when I click the button and reload my game_loop it will work  ? if I have `quit = False
while not quit:` on my entire game? also  I do have [runninggame on my main loop](https://gyazo.com/98fd46145d962f9fb5208f90b8047e34)

Comment: still doesnt work  [quit](https://gyazo.com/7c142376eccb18856ac8d0f3540a4d4c) [main loop](https://gyazo.com/ca1e15b603db1e1fd53e5f6c01075bfb)

Comment: I think the problem lies in the endscreen function where you call pygame.quit() and quit().  You must change that. I will update my question to help.

Comment: still no luck [image](https://gyazo.com/0ea5cf5ea763885855730b66367aa146) [Game Scren](https://gyazo.com/8dd47538a371638e84de6a4d4dfba638)

Comment: heres my full code [script](https://pastebin.com/5CFDEfMe) I feel like I am messing up one thing but idk what it is

Comment: So, it looked like some restructuring was needed but I thought it would just be easier for me to do them and explain them than for me to tell you what changes would be necessary. So here is the modified version if your code: https://pastebin.com/A4swYcyC. Let me know if you have any issues or if there are any bugs since I can't test it. Also I will update the answer with all the change made.

Comment: it says "end_game" is not defined but then I changed it to my main game_loop() I am still not restarting the whole game when I click play again [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/e365083b93697516162f74188e3b9e6b)

Comment: I have updated the paste bin again hopefully it works this time.

Comment: [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/433496c9f4d5df34e1cdd5ae0880a1fe) still no luck doesnt reset my game]

Comment: I found the problem. It turned out that the break was passed inside the event for loop which just caused that to break instead of the game while loop. So I just set `runninggame = True` above the break and it should all work fine this time. I have updated the script again so feel free to just copy and paste that.

Comment: sorry if I am litterally annoying with with these problems  I think the issue just got worser with I die and click play again it blinks to the game but doesnt end it then it goes to my start screen [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/eab8cb0061e6ad3027bc4582ae755b0c)

Comment: For the start game screen popping up, all you need to do is move it outside the main while loop and call it one time before starting the game. But i am not sure why you immediately die the second you load in. That doesn't make sense.